# Is this the correct way to query 2 mysql tables with php and a $_POST variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to figure out the best way to return an order from a database. I've come up with this, and it's working the way I want (I think) it gives me the results I'm looking for but I wanted to know if its correct or if there is a better way.

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('', '', ''); 
if (!$conn) 
{ 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
mysql_select_db($dbs, $conn);

$Order_ID = $_POST['Order_ID'];
//$Order_ID = '1001';

    $queryOrderHead = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Order_ID = '$Order_ID' ";

    $queryOrderLines = "SELECT *

    FROM Order_LineDetails 
    WHERE Order_LineDetails.Order_ID = '$Order_ID'

";
        if ($queryRunHead = mysql_query($queryOrderHead)){

                while ($info_HEAD = mysql_fetch_array($queryRunHead))       
                {
                    $OrderID_HEAD = $info_HEAD['Order_ID'];         
                    $User_ID_HEAD = $info_HEAD['User_ID'];  
                    $Customer_ID_HEAD = $info_HEAD['Customer_ID'];                          
                    echo $OrderID_HEAD.' '.$User_ID_HEAD.' '.$Customer_ID_HEAD.'<br>';
                }

                $queryRunLines = mysql_query($queryOrderLines);
                while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($queryRunLines))       
                {
                    $OrderID = $info['Order_ID'];           
                    $OrderLineID = $info['OrderLineItem_ID'];           
                    echo $OrderID.' '.$OrderLineID.'<br>';
                }

        } else {
        echo mysql_error();         
        }

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

So what it does, is it uses the `Order_ID` val from the $_POST and runs the first query then on success it uses the same `Order_ID` and loops the second query and gets all the `Order_LineDetails` from a different table.

Other than the `mysql_real_escape()` tags....

Any pointers or ideas???

Comment: You could eliminate the two calls to the database and simply make one call which joins the two tables together based on the order ID.  So something like `SELECT O.Order_ID, O.user_ID, O.Customer_ID, O.OrderLIneItem_ID FROM Orders O LEFT JOIN order_lineDetails OLD ON O.Order_ID = OLD.Order_ID WHERE O.Order_ID = '$Order_ID'`  In theory this should be faster due to fewer calls to the database, but you're returning more data for each record which could negate the benefit depending on the volume of data being duplicated.

Comment: What about if the first query will always return 1 row of data, and the second query could return 1 to 100+ rows?

Comment: You're selecting the order, then the order items. Nothing wrong with that approach. Placing into an array would be better organization.

Comment: Make sure to sanitize the value of the post variable, e.g. `$Order_ID = intval($_POST['Order_ID']);` to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any pointers or ideas???

There's nothing wrong with selecting the order first, then its items. However, you'd benefit from organizing the data into an array structure as well as following better naming conventions (both for variables and database schema):

```
$orderId = $_POST['order_id'];

// order_id should be an INT, so no quotes. 
// Also look into parameterized queries with PDO as the mysql_* functions are archaic!
$sqlOrder = "SELECT * 
             FROM orders 
             WHERE order_id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($orderId);

$order = array();
if ($resOrder = mysql_query($sqlOrder)) {

    if ($rowOrder = mysql_fetch_array($resOrder)) {
        $order = $rowOrder;
        // echo $rowOrder['order_id'].' '.$rowOrder['user_id'].' '.$rowOrder['customer_id']."<br />\n";

        $sqlOrderLines = "SELECT * 
                  FROM order_lines
                  WHERE order_lines.order_id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($orderId);

        if ($resOrderLines = mysql_query($sqlOrderLines)) {
            $order['order_lines'] = array();
            while ($rowOrderLines = mysql_fetch_array($resOrderLines)) {
                $order['order_lines'][] = $rowOrderLines;                 
                // echo $rowOrderLines['order_id'].' '.$rowOrderLines['order_line_id']."<br />\n";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Order not found'.
    }



} else {
    echo mysql_error();         
}

// debug
print_r($order);
```

Comment: Explain the downvote. He's in need of such pointers.